# Filter List of Tuples with longest String

Tags: haskell, filter, tuples, string-length

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to filter a list of tuples when using the 2nd element's (String) length and returning the correct tuple, if there is any at all..

```
Prelude> let lst = [(a,rr), (b,rr), (c, rrr), (d, rrrr)]

Prelude> filter ((>4).(length snd)) lst

[d, rrrr)]
```

There is an error when trying to execute it, that length has too many arguments..

Can someone help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be `(>4) . length . snd`.

Answer (score 3):

```
filter ((>4).(length snd)) lst
```

It looks like you have the right idea with this, but as you note it doesn't compile. Although when I try, the error is different from the one you mention about `length` having too many arguments - you've given it one argument here, which is the correct number. However, the argument you've given it is a function (`snd`, which gives you the second element of a pair), and it expects a list - since there is no way to consider a function as a list, the compiler rejects this as meaningless. (Even if this were not a problem, `length snd` would result in an `Int`, and you can't use this as an argument of the `.` operator, which needs a function on either side. And this is what GHC actually complains about when I try to run your code: `Couldn't match expected type '([Char], [Char]) -> Integer' with actual type 'Int' In the second argument of '(.)', namely '(length snd)'`)

@WillemVanOnsem has already shown you how to fix it, so let's take a look at that. It is indeed quite similar to yours:

```
filter ((>4) . length . snd)) lst
```

The `.` operator, as you seem to know, applies first the function to its right, then the function to its left to the result. So the expression `(>4) . length . snd` means, given a pair, take the second element, then take its length (it's assumed it is a list, or this won't compile), then checks whether the resulting number is greater than 4 or not. In other words, `(>4) . length . snd)` is a predicate of type `(a, [b]) -> Bool` which tells you whether the list in the second slot of the pair has more than 4 elements or not. [The term "predicate" just means any function which returns a `Bool` - it's a test applied to elements of the type you're interested in, as used in `filter` and many related functions.] And this of course is exactly what you're aiming for.

So to sum up, the only difference between your answer and the correct one is that between `length snd` (giving the `snd` function as an argument to `length`, which is meaningless), and `length . snd` (the function given by applying first `snd`, then `length` to its result). They may look similar, but they actually mean very different things.

I'm sure that with a bit more practice you'll be able to get things like this right on your own, and understand what GHC is telling you when it gives you a compilation error.

(PS: your code actually fails in the first place because `a`, `rr` etc. are variables that you haven't bound to any values. I've assumed that they are all meant to be strings, especially as you refer to taking the length of the `r..r` values - in this case they need to be enclosed in double quotes: `("a", "rr")` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is grand but there remains the problem of having to know the longest string length within the function to match or exceed it. What if you don't know the longest field length and can't code it in your function? The `lf` function spits out the length of the longest string. I do think a lambda in the filter predicate is more intelligible.

lf has to keep track of the longest string so far so it can't pass tuples but only single values.

```
ls = [('a',"rr"), ('b',"rr"), ('c', "rrr"), ('d', "rrrr")]
lf = (\a b -> if (length $ snd b) > a then (length $ snd b) else a)
filter (\t -> (length $ snd t) == (foldl lf 0 ls)) ls
```

[('d',"rrrr")]